# Are these users not obviously ban-worthy?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged two user's posts asking for a review-ban.

> declined - You're going to need to point out some specific examples here, because I'm not seeing anything ban-worthy at first glance.

So, ok, neither of them are approving *everything*, but…

[image: 17 positive, 3 negative]

[image: A lot of things clicked...]

That has to be at least a *little bit* suspicious. Let's dive deeper. Here's one where they both review, and both wrong:

[image: This is where I found them]

Honest mistake?

[image: No.]

[image: No.]

No.

Is there anything *good* about the reviews of these users? Why was my flag declined?

Comment: No, they're not *obviously* ban-worthy. In fact, just your first screenshot made me angry. Just because a question contains the word "why" it is primarily opinion based and this person is a crappy reviewer? Seriously?

Comment: @animuson Not because of the one word. I just chose to quote that because it *is* evidence. Of course, reading the whole thing would be better than one word scribbled down in off-red.

Comment: I don't find these reviews *particularly* egregious (though I disagree with some of these reviews) -- personally, it's understandable how one can come to the conclusion that this reviewer did.

Comment: @Qantas Stupidity is understandable. But why do we need to tolerate it? Bans are not that big of a deal.

Comment: Also, low reputation is not a reason to ban someone at all. I've seen 25k users approve vandalism in suggested edits, 10k users leave open questions saying pretty much *literally* "plz gimme the codez", and so on.

Comment: @Qantas I didn't say low reputation is a reason to ban. I said that, in addition to suspicious review history, it is a reason to investigate further.

Comment: Seriously? I put like an hour of research and red-cirlce effort into this for people to say "meh u rong i revw lk thi 2 mod no help"

Comment: @bjb568: where did someone say that? If you're referring to what I've said, that wasn't what I intended to say.

Comment: @Qantas No, there's a deleted comment.

Comment: Do you really need to call them out in public just because you didn't like the result of the moderator flag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I flagged two user's posts asking for a review-ban.

Why wouldn't you flag the examples of the posts that've been poorly-reviewed?

I mean, that's where you started, right? And you found more examples as you went along?

That's where the moderators are gonna have to *end up* - if you already have that information in front of you, why not pass it along?

Comment: I thot it was fairly obvious seeing walls of "No action needed" and "approve". But good idea, I didn't think of that.

Comment: @bjb568 - Keep in mind that someone's review history will be tilted towards showing "No Action Needed" reviews, since if they flagged bad posts and those were removed, they won't show in the visible list of reviews. Likewise for "Recommend Deletion" votes in the Low Quality Posts queue. We have the ability to see the rest of these reviews, which can paint a different picture.

Comment: @Brad At the time the reviews were still pending so I don't think that was the case.