# Do I need to include examples of bad reviews on all robo-reviewing flags?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I found 4 robo-reviewers from [this crazy post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24851906/revisions)...

Normally I find a couple examples of reviews for each user that I think are obviously wrong and link to them when I flag. But I thot it wasn't necessary.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/181174/mohammed-arif?tab=activity - *helpful - I only found the review you were referring to here by blind chance, but you need to provide links to the specific ban-worthy reviews in the future or these will likely be declined.*

[image: Approve...]

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108495/ryan-kempt?tab=activity - *declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it*

[image: No Action Needed...]

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1282539/yorye-nathan?tab=activity - Awaiting review

[image: Approve..]

https://stackoverflow.com/users/969210/frederick-behrends?tab=activity - Awaiting review

[image: Approve...]

It seems pretty obvious to me that these are robos, do I still need to provide examples?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[We've had this conversation before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255860/19679). If you found specific instances of reviews that should not have been approved, tell us that in your flag. Frankly, just flagging a slew of people with flags that only read "Robo-reviewing" isn't particularly helpful. You're forcing us to pull up every single review each reviewer has made recently to try to find the one or two that might have tipped you off.

You only see their public review history. That will by necessity be skewed towards approvals, since things they vote to delete in the Low Quality Posts queue, or that they flag in other queues, will usually end up deleted. Therefore, those elements will not appear in their public review history. In general, outside of suggested edit reviews, public review histories are not good indications of how someone is reviewing. Flagging based on that is usually unproductive.

For one of the users you flagged as "robo-reviewing", I could clearly see in their public review history that they had rejected many bad suggested edits and voted to close bad posts. Privately, I saw they'd flagged many low quality items as such. That's not someone blindly clicking buttons, so I declined that. If you had a specific post or two that was obviously ban-worthy in that, I couldn't see it, thus your flag was not useful.

[People get really angry if you ban them from review for no obvious reason.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265571/approved-suggested-edit-from-a-known-troll) I need to have a good case to present to them when I ban someone from review, so they have to be approving things that they obviously didn't read (like spam or vandalism) or be exhibiting a clear pattern of review abuse. When you make accusations against another reviewer, I would like to see proof or something more than just "robo-reviewer" in your flag.

Comment: Oh, I see. You need an example for the ban message. And it isn't obvious that I'm talking about edits so invisible "delete"s can make it harder to tell what I'm talking about.

Comment: @VotetoClose - It was more the comments all over that where people expressed their disapproval. I'm sure your inbox is still recovering from that, as is mine.