# Approved suggested edit that breaks the original answer

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

One of my answers has been edited ([approved by suggested edits review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8735508)), but the edit turns a valid response to an erroneous one. I've just edited it to revert to the original answer.

Do approvers and suggesters receive any notice? Is there a way to inform them that their review was wrong? I saw that one of the users has approved 855 edit suggestions and rejected only two edit suggestions; should I have raised a flag to require a moderator's attention?

Comment: I looked at the user you alluded to, initially expecting it to be the useless reviewing figures which haven't worked correctly for ages. However, these ones look accurate. The two rejects I can find on the first five pages of reviews are both audits. May be worth a mod reviewing the reviewer.

Comment: Ok flag has been raised thank you

Comment: That edit should not at all have been accepted...

Comment: @BillWoodger The figures aren't *quite* accurate. I scrolled through the first 30 pages of the user's review history; most pages had one reject (and one page even had three!). Looks like they've mastered the audit system pretty well.

Comment: What about the notifications? Is there any feedback sent to reviewers?

Comment: @Kayasax Wouldn't that be [a nice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298822/176646) [feature](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298174/176646)?

Comment: Yep already up vote there

Comment: Just a tip in case you're not aware of it: in the edit history, your old version had a "rollback" link that you could have used instead of manually undoing the edit. It's up to you and in this case it wouldn't have made all that much of a difference, but in general, it can save quite a bit of time.

Comment: To be honest: I am one of the few who rejected the edit but I did so on the basis that it changes almost nothing in something which was posted a long time ago. I didn't figure it worthy enough to bump this back into activity. I did not reject it because I witnessed the edit was wrong. You are right that plenty of people approve for no good reason; I think in this case the reviewing have been done by people who aren't actually familiar with the subject material (me included).

Comment: @Gimby thank for your honesty. I wonder if the same things will happen if the reviewers  were allowed only if they have a certain amount of reputation on the tags used by the reeview's question ?

Comment: @Kayasax that would only make the problem worse; plenty of edits you can review without having knowledge of the tags. Especially rejections in my experience, most rejections I do are based on "defacing" or pointlessness and not based on factual incorrectness. Long story short: this would be an example of the exception to the rule.

Comment: *"I saw that one of the users has approved 855 edit suggestions and rejected only two edit suggestions; should I have raised a flag to require a moderator's attention?"* Don't forget that this counter still can be incorrect. For example, my stat is reported as *"Tom has approved 1111 edit suggestions and rejected 8 edit suggestions"* which is nonsense. The rate is more like 1:1 or 3:2 (approved:rejected).

Comment: @Tom these stats should better not be shown if they are such counterfeit

Comment: @Kayasax Right and this is already a topic on Meta: [Suggested edits showing the wrong stats](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272597) (there are maybe more question about that). So yes, it might be better to hide these wrong stats until that bug is fixed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you see a particularly egregious edit being approved, and have evidence that a certain reviewer may be abusing the review system, it's perfectly fine to raise a custom moderator flag pointing this out. I wouldn't do that for every bad review you saw, but if one was especially terrible (approving outright spam, vandalism, or other destructive actions) it could warrant this.

When you do flag for something like this, [please provide the specific evidence you have for someone abusing the review system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266205/19679) (the particular review, their history, etc.). We need to have something to go on before we take the time to look into someone's review history.

I looked into the review history of the reviewers here and took appropriate actions based on that. Thanks for your flag about this.

Comment: Thank you and sorry to have spend your time with the lack of detail. May I ask what is an appropriate action in cases like that?

Comment: @Kayasax - Your flag was perfectly fine. You provided the specific edit that was troubling and enough information for us to act on. That's how I'd recommend reporting this in the future.

Comment: @BradLarson If I find an edit that breaks an answer, but I don't have any idea whether it's a "problem" reviewer, should I just reveres/correct with another edit or flag to a moderator?